# Integral or Series Closed Form Inquiry

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question, asking-questions

I know it's a dumb question still

I don't have premium access to Mathematica or Wolfram Alpha, so I sometimes get stuck. Can I ask on Math Stack Exchange community for help finding the closed form of this integral or series using Mathematica?

Main question: Are These Types of Questions allowed on MSE?

Comment: re Mathematica I believe you could use this - https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198839/how-to-add-a-front-end-to-the-free-wolfram-engine?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 6):

A key part of our mission on this site is to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others.  So, if you ask us to compute an integral of some very specific function, that doesn't sound like it would advance that mission.  An answer would help you, but it's not clear how it would help anyone else.

To make the question a good fit here, provide context about why the question is interesting and relevant to others.  If you don't have such context, then the question might not be appropriate here.  Similarly, "no clue" questions (where you say "I have no clue how to solve this") are more likely to be viewed negatively.

We are not a replacement for Wolfram Alpha where you type your equation into this site and we solve it for you.  That is not likely to be well-received.

See also [Please provide context.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29118/14578), [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/14578).